# TensorFlow 2.0 tf.random.set_seed not working since I am getting different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using `tf.random.set_seed` to assure the reproducibility of my experiments but getting different results in terms of loss after training my model multiple times. I am monitoring the learning curve of each experiment using Tensorboard, but I am getting different values of loss and accuracy.

Comment: I believe you must reset the kernel for testing. If you do things in sequence, the second time will probably not be equal to the first time.

Comment: You can also try setting the numpy seed, and maybe pass seeds directly to the layers/methods that use random values.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMöller. It works now.

Comment: Hello @Khalil Mlayhi. I try setting the numpy seed, but it's not fixed. Would you tell me your final solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

To reproduce same results, you can create function as below and pass seeds directly to the layers as mentioned Daniel in the comments.

```
def reset_random_seeds():
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(2)
   tf.random.set_seed(2)
   np.random.seed(2)
   random.seed(2)
```

Please refer complete code in below, which reproduced same results

```
import os
####*IMPORANT*: Have to do this line *before* importing tensorflow
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(2)

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers 
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def reset_random_seeds():
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(2)
   tf.random.set_seed(2)
   np.random.seed(2)
   random.seed(2)

#make some random data
reset_random_seeds()
NUM_ROWS = 1000
NUM_FEATURES = 10
random_data = np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS, NUM_FEATURES))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=random_data, columns=['x_' + str(ii) for ii in range(NUM_FEATURES)])
y = df.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS))

def run(x, y):
    reset_random_seeds()

    model = keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(40, input_dim=df.shape[1], activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
        ])
    NUM_EPOCHS = 100
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=0)
    predictions = model.predict(x).flatten()
    loss = model.evaluate(x,  y) #This prints out the loss by side-effect

#With Tensorflow 2.0 this is now reproducible! 
run(df, y)
run(df, y)
run(df, y)
```

Output:

```
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5633
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5633
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5633
```

Comment: For me, if I ignore this line: `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(2)` at the second line of the code, and I use it only inside the `reset_random_seeds` function, I still get reproducible results

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed` may also need to be set (or, for instnace, `keras.utils.set_random_seed`, if you imported keras from tensorflow).

Docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed

Answer (score -1):

for tensorflow 2, use **tf.random.set_seed(seed)** instead